# How to set drawing automatically when using pen in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, digitization, bamboo, pen

I have Bamboo pen and am remember, that it was starting to draw automatically in MS One Note. But now pen acts exactly like mouse, i.e. I need to choose draw mode explicitly to draw with pen.

How to set back?

OneNote is 2010.

**UPDATE**

I have my pen in pen mode currently.

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Driver update helped. Previous drivers were installed by me in times of Windows 7, later windows was upgraded to 8, while Bamboo drivers remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I suspect that you have changed the pen settings in the Bamboo settings app.</strike>

You can have it act as a pen (absolute positioning) or as a mouse (relative positioning) - I think I got those the right way round.

OneNote recognises the presence of a pen automatically as that is what it was originally designed for.

UPDATE: How about the OneNote settings. Have a look in the Advanced Options and make sure that the option "Automatically switch between inking, selection, typing, and panning" is **selected**.

Sorry about the trial and error. I can't use my Bamboo on Windows 8 and my Windows 7 laptop is locked down so I can't use it there either.

Comment: I have pen in pen mode in settings.

Comment: I have option "Automatically switch between...." ON. Turning it on and off has no effect.